# How to temporarily disable a button within an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, disabled-control, prop

In my Javascript code, I wrote an Ajax call where a couple of `for loop` cycles call two JSON files; some functions are called when some events occur and a `Search` button is clicked: tables containing data from the APIs requests are displayed.

I want to temporarily disable the `Search` button when these data are looked for within the Ajax calls, and then enable it again once the operation was carried out, in a way similar to what happens in the `setTimeout()` Method, but without having to set a number of milliseconds (I cannot specify it previously for the number of milliseconds depends on the slowness of the internet connection and other factors...).

How to set the `.prop("disabled", false);` temporarily within a callback function? In other terms, how to temporarily disable a button within an Ajax call?

Comment: You disable it _before_ you make the AJAX call, and enable it again in the sucess callback …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `beforeSend` and `complete` for this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        // disable your button here
        .prop("disabled", true);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //success
    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
    },
    complete: function() {
        // enable your button here
        .prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank, it works. May I omit the 'beforeSend' and 'complete' functions and just write '$('#IDofTheButton).prop("disabled", true)' and '$('#IDofTheButton).prop("disabled", false)'?

Comment: Yes you can omit. In that case you need to disable the button just before the ajax call and can enable the button in success function.

Comment: thanks @ravibagul91  I added the '.prop("disabled", true);' inside the success callback function and the  '.prop("disabled", false);' outside the ajax call, is it correct?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12CZQ2fL1cGHnJISfmq3vcCPKvy6iQPju/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

inject the object instance into the event handlers.

Checkout the possible event handlers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

instead of `Console.log` call our `object.prop("disabled",false")` there

Answer (score 0):

using JavaScript Fetch API

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="loadData()">Change Content</button>
    <div id="response">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function loadData() {

      document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;

      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((resp) => resp.text()) // Transform the response into text
        .then((data) => {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =
            data;
          document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = false;
        });

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

using plain old javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="loadData()">Change Content</button>
    <div id="response">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function loadData() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
        document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = false;
      };

      xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", true);
      xhttp.send();
      document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = '';
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```